# exponential matrix function definition?

Tags: r

I am running a machine that only has R 2.10 and cannot be updated (this is a fact: it cannot be changed).

I need to use the "expm" package's functionality for taking the kth power of a matrix (it is the function `%^%`) but I cannot figure out how to copy the source code, since the earliest version of this package was made for versions *later* than R 2.10. On R, after installing the `expm` package, running:

```
 library(expm)
 getAnywhere('%^%')
```

gives me the source code, but then when I copy this source code in the form `%^% <- *source code*`, I get the error

```
Error in stopifnot(is.numeric(x) || is(x, "dMatrix"), length(d <- dim(x)) ==  : 
 object 'x' not found
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to use the original implementation of %^% via source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks ` to denote a non-syntactic name.

```
`%^%` <- ....
```

Comment: that worked! after I copy it and try to use it, though, I get the error `Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`. I tried setting `arg=NULL` but it didn't work. Do you know what I should set `arg` as? I'm trying to take a 1700 x 1700 data frame to the -2 power.